# How to export "simplices" array from Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, delaunay

I am using the "Delaunay triangulation" module in from "scipy.spatial."
I am able to generate an array (actually an ndarray, since I am using x, y and z coordinates) from the "simplices," but unable to export it into any format I can use for further processing.

The code is straightforward:

```
tri = Delaunay(points)
a = np.array(points[tri.simplices])
```

What I get looks like this:

```
   [[7.02192702e+05, 7.53337067e+06, 1.43116411e+02],
    [7.02275075e+05, 7.53339801e+06, 1.53508313e+02],
    [7.02073353e+05, 7.53340902e+06, 1.40979450e+02],
    [7.02288667e+05, 7.53338498e+06, 1.52185457e+02]],

   ...,

   [[7.02038856e+05, 7.53333613e+06, 1.39584833e+02],
    [7.02069568e+05, 7.53327029e+06, 1.46902739e+02],
    [7.02062213e+05, 7.53331215e+06, 1.31241316e+02],
    [7.02040635e+05, 7.53329922e+06, 1.30787203e+02]],...
```

By playing around with it I can export it into an extended string:

```
702299.971067+7533414.077516+163.2373+...
```

But I would prefer to have it in a .csv file with columns, or convert that extended string into a table or array with a set number of columns.

I assume I'm doing something wrong in saving or writing the output, but can't find any obvious solutions to saving/exporting arrays online anywhere.

Any ideas? suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Once it's in an `np.ndarray` format, just use `np.savetxt()` to save the array to a `.txt` file. (see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

This is the simplest method I know of.